# Use the Android USB Audio functionality

Tags: android, audio, usb

I would like to use the USB Audio functionality of Android 5, but I have not found any indication about how to use this functionality or how to implement it.

Does anyone knows how to use it? There is very little in the docs so it doesn't really help me.